# Заменить mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query())

Tags: php, pdo

Надо достать инфу с одной таблицы по данным второй.
только что-то не выходит.

```
$post = DB :: $dbs -> query("SELECT * FROM `book` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 12");
while($posts =  $post->fetch()) 
{
    $user = DB :: $dbs -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '".$posts['id']."' ");
    echo $user->login; // пустота
}
```

читал, что `prepare == m_f_a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = DB :: $dbs -> query('SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE true', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $user = DB :: $dbs -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '".$posts['id']."' ");
    $user->execute()
    print_r($user->fetch());
}
```

Comment: PDOStatement_ Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '1' )

Comment: @Александр поправил ответ